# ERROR al tratar de usar la función load_dataset de PixelLib Python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de cargar un dataset de imágenes ("cars") para modelar con la librería PixelLib. Hice exactamente lo recomendado: mediante Labelme creé los .json de las imagenes para train y test y me dispongo a cargar el dataset:

```
import pixellib
from pixellib.custom_train import instance_custom_training
vis_img = instance_custom_training()
vis_img.load_dataset("cars")
vis_img.visualize_sample()
```

Cuando ejecuto me salta el siguiente error:

> ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has
> no identity

Las imagenes fueron validadas y están ok. Alguna idea??? Gracias